# Change value of a table cell with WatIn

Tags: c#, html, watin

Using WatiN, can I access an url and change the value of a html table cell defined this way :

```
<TABLE class=table1>
<TBODY>
    <TR class=dis>
        <TD> rowSpan="1" colSpan="1"
        Famille
        <INPUT name="familySearch" onkeyup="toMaj(document.forms[0],'familySearch');changeFormEltFocus(3, 'eng.facLab');" onfocus=onKeyBack() maxLength=3 size=3 value="AAA"></input>
        <A onclick="popupFamily('RFOS');" tabIndex=-1 href="#"><IMG border=0 hspace=4 alt=" " src="/ppm/images/picto_loupe.gif" align=absMiddle></A>
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TBODY>
```

I tried to do it using :

```
browser.Table(Find.ByClass("table1")).TableRows[0].TableCells[0].SetAttributeValue("AAA", "X82");
```

But I'm getting an error saying I can't access the cell. Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the TR/TD?

Comment: I edited my post, is the TR/TD clear ? Is the "value" field writable? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try focusing and then setting the value.

```
browser.TextField(Find.ByName("familySearch")).Focus();
browser.TextField(Find.ByName("familySearch")).TypeText("AAA");
```

Comment: I've been using the browser.Texfield with success up until now but it doesn't seem to work with tables. Focusing didn't solve the problem and I get this error :

"An unhandled exception of type 'WatiN.Core.Exceptions.ElementNotFoundException' occurred in WatiN.Core.dll

Additional information: Could not find INPUT (hidden) or INPUT (password) or INPUT (text) or INPUT (textarea) or TEXTAREA element tag matching criteria: Attribute 'name' equals 'familySearch'"